# Autodesk Inventor script to open .JT and export .JT (with specific options)

Tags: vba, autodesk, autodesk-inventor

I regularly need to export existing JT models to tesselated JT models which takes a looong time on my computer. So I was wondering if this can be done via a script? Ideally embedded in an Excel file where I provide a list of JT filenames and paths, but one by one would also be okay. As long as I don't have to manually open and export each file in Inventor.

Import options that need to be set:
- Object filter: Solids

Export options:
- Object Types to export: all ticked
- Output: Facets only
- Version: 9.5
- Structure: Monolithic

Can this be done? I have some VBA experience, however absolutely no experience specifically with Inventor as far as scripting/command line stuff goes ....

Thanks!

dreamingof8a

Answer (score 0):

I don't have at the moment the solution for the Options. But this is the script to export to JT.
It's based on the STEP example in the Inventor API documentation.

```
Public Sub ExportToJT(inventorFile As String, jtFile As String)
    ' Get the JT translator Add-In.
    Dim oJTTranslator As TranslatorAddIn
    Set oJTTranslator = ThisApplication.ApplicationAddIns.ItemById("{16625A0E-F58C-4488-A969-E7EC4F99CACD}")

    If oJTTranslator Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not access JT translator."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim oContext As TranslationContext
    Set oContext = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateTranslationContext
    Dim oOptions As NameValueMap
    Set oOptions = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateNameValueMap
    If oJTTranslator.HasSaveCopyAsOptions(ThisApplication.ActiveDocument, oContext, oOptions) Then

        ' Other options...
        'oOptions.Value("Author") = ""
        'oOptions.Value("Authorization") = ""
        'oOptions.Value("Description") = ""
        'oOptions.Value("Organization") = ""

        oContext.Type = kFileBrowseIOMechanism

        Dim oData As DataMedium
        Set oData = ThisApplication.TransientObjects.CreateDataMedium
        oData.FileName = jtFile

        Call oJTTranslator.SaveCopyAs(ThisApplication.ActiveDocument, oContext, oOptions, oData)
    End If
End Sub
```